# Python: access class property from string

Tags: python, syntax

I have a class like the following:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
        self.other_data = []

    def doSomething(self, source):
        // if source = 'other_data' how to access self.other_data
```

I want to pass a string for the source variable in `doSomething` and access the class member of the same name.

I have tried `getattr` which only works on functions (from what I can tell) as well as having `User` extend `dict` and using `self.__getitem__`, but that doesn't work either. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 394, accepted):

`x = getattr(self, source)` will work just perfectly if `source` names ANY attribute of self, including the `other_data` in your example.

Comment: (realizing this is an old thread).  I was confused/always forget this because of dicts.  If I want to get a value from a dict, I can say: myDict.get('keyy'), so I would expect attributes to work the same way:  myObject.getattr('attr_name').  But instead they take the object as a first argument...ok to do, but the apparent inconsistency is why I had trouble.

Answer (score 269):

A picture's worth a thousand words:

```
>>> class c:
        pass
o = c()
>>> setattr(o, "foo", "bar")
>>> o.foo
'bar'
>>> getattr(o, "foo")
'bar'
```

Comment: I like this answer in particular because it illustrates, simply, that the getattr() function works outside class methods as well.

Comment: It does not, however, demonstrate that `getattr()` and `setattr()` work inside the `__init__()` function, as well, which they do. So, instead of doing `self[myStr] = myValue`, which won't work, you **can** do `setattr(self, myStr, myValue)`, which does work, even inside of `__init__()`. Just to clarify that for others.

Answer (score 115):

- **`getattr(x, 'y')`** is equivalent to **`x.y`**
- **`setattr(x, 'y', v)`** is equivalent to **`x.y = v`**
- **`delattr(x, 'y')`** is equivalent to **`del x.y`**

Comment: How I can access `x.y` according to the value string of `v`?

Comment: @user2284570: If `v` contains the string `'y'` then `getattr(x, v)` gives the value of `x.y`.

Comment: @md2perpe except it is not the case.

Comment: @user2284570: How was your case, then?

Answer (score 5):

Extending Alex's answer slightly:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = [1,2,3]
        self.other_data = [4,5,6]
    def doSomething(self, source):
        dataSource = getattr(self,source)
        return dataSource

A = User()
print A.doSomething("data")
print A.doSomething("other_data")
```

will yield:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

However, personally I don't think that's great style - `getattr` will let you access any attribute of the instance, including things like the `doSomething` method itself, or even the `__dict__` of the instance. I would suggest that instead you implement a dictionary of data sources, like so:

```
class User:
    def __init__(self):

        self.data_sources = {
            "data": [1,2,3],
            "other_data":[4,5,6],
        }

    def doSomething(self, source):
        dataSource = self.data_sources[source]
        return dataSource

A = User()

print A.doSomething("data")
print A.doSomething("other_data")
```

again yielding:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: I didn't explain properly... my apologies.  I am able to get the data via the string.  However, I am having problems setting the data using the above methods.  

Specifically I have tried 
getattr(self, "other_data") = [1, 2, 3]
as well as 
self.__setitem__("other_data", [1, 2, 3])

Comment: @sberry2A, `getattr()` is only for getting, `setattr()` is for setting. You can't assign to the return value from `getattr()`.