# Accessing an attribute using a variable in Python

Tags: python

How do I reference `this_prize.left` or `this_prize.right` using a variable?

```
from collections import namedtuple
import random 

Prize = namedtuple("Prize", ["left", "right"]) 
this_prize = Prize("FirstPrize", "SecondPrize")

if random.random() > .5:
    choice = "left"
else:
    choice = "right"

# retrieve the value of "left" or "right" depending on the choice
print("You won", this_prize.choice)

AttributeError: 'Prize' object has no attribute 'choice'
```

Comment: FYI - You can skip the collections import and just use a dictionary to do the same thing:
    >>> this_prize = {"left": "FirstPrize", "right":"FirstPrize"}
    >>> this_prize[choice]
    >'FirstPrize'

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167398/python-access-class-property-from-string

Answer (score 111, accepted):

The expression `this_prize.choice` is telling the interpreter that you want to access an attribute of this_prize with the name "choice".  But this attribute does not exist in this_prize.

What you actually want is to return the attribute of this_prize identified by the ***value*** of choice.  So you just need to change your last line using the [getattr()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) method...

```
from collections import namedtuple

import random

Prize = namedtuple("Prize", ["left", "right" ])

this_prize = Prize("FirstPrize", "SecondPrize")

if random.random() > .5:
    choice = "left"
else:
    choice = "right"

# retrieve the value of "left" or "right" depending on the choice

print "You won", getattr(this_prize, choice)
```

Answer (score 113):

```
getattr(this_prize, choice)
```

From http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr:

> `getattr(object, name)` returns the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a string

Comment: I think this is the generic way to accomplish the task. Since it makes use of the built-in function designed for the purpose, it should really be the preferred answer. (Yes, I realize this is an old question, but it still shows up in Google.)

Comment: And, naturally the counterpart is `setattr`. `setattr(x, 'foobar', 123)` is the same as `x.foobar = 123`.