# Python: access class attribute by variable

Tags: python, variables

in python how to access instance's attribute as cls.variable format?

(in ruby, it can be in format cls.#{variable} )

```
>>>cls.classname
u'CIM_RegisteredProfile'

>>>var='classname'

>>>cls.var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 0, in <module>
AttributeError: 'CIMClass' object has no attribute 'var'
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python: Accessing an attribute using a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157035/python-accessing-an-attribute-using-a-variable)

Answer (score 19):

Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
var = 'classname'
getattr(cls, var)
```

Comment: b="a."+var
b
'a.classname'
eval(b)
u'CIM_RegisteredProfile'

Comment: @brike, try to avoid `eval` whenever possible. Read the answers on [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/86513/why-is-using-javascript-eval-function-a-bad-idea) or google "eval is evil".

Comment: `getattr` is the Pythonic answer.

Comment: I'm tempted to flag that suggestion of eval as an alternative as 'offensive'