# How to dynamically access class properties in Python?

Tags: python, class

Let's say I create an instance of a class and want to assign some values to its public properties. Usually, this would be done like this:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.text = None

myclass = MyClass()
myclass.name = 'My name'
```

But, what if a write a function that takes a class as parameter and I would like to assign some values to the public properties of that class dynamically - that is via variables and loops (without knowing how many there are or what they are called.)

The obvious would be:

```
myclass = MyClass()
myclass['name'] = "My name"
```

But that doesn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Also, this is a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167398/python-access-class-property-from-string

Answer (score 57, accepted):

```
setattr(my_class_instance, 'attr_name', attr_value)
```

Answer (score 20):

After reading rejected [Syntax For Dynamic Attribute Access](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0363/) I'm using a mixin class providing dictionary-style access to an object's attributes :

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = None
        self.text = None
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return getattr(self, name)
    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        return setattr(self, name, value)
    def __delitem__(self, name):
        return delattr(self, name)
    def __contains__(self, name):
        return hasattr(self, name)
```

While still being able to set attributes directly:

```
myclass = MyClass()
myclass.name = "foo"
myclass.text = "bar"
```

it's then possible to set them dynamically :

```
for attr in ('name', 'text'):
    myclass[attr] = confirm(attr, default=myclass[attr])
```

Comment: I only needed the `def __getitem__` two lines in my case.  Worked great!

Answer (score 2):

Using `dir` with  `setattr` should do the job

```
class MyClass:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = None
    self.text = None

myclass = MyClass()
myclass.name = 'My name'

for prop in dir(myclass):
    print '%s:%s'%(prop,getattr(myclass,prop))

print

for prop in dir(myclass):
    if prop[:2]!='__' and prop[-2:]!='__':
        print prop[-2:]
        setattr(myclass,prop,"Foo Bar")

for prop in dir(myclass):
    print '%s:%s'%(prop,getattr(myclass,prop))
```

But be careful because this code also sets `'__doc__', '__init__', '__module__'` properties to "Foo Bar". So you will have to take care of avoiding certain things given to you by `dir` (especially those which start and end with `__` double underscores).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solution is a good or bad idea.
But this works for me.

```
myclass = MyClass()
myclass.__dict__['name'] = "My name"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).