# How to specify GAE Python ndb field name based on a variable

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

In storing data into an NDB, I'd like to obtain the name of the field from a string variable (e.g., field_name2 = "userid"). Is there a way? thanks in advance.

```
class Account(ndb.Model):
     username = ndb.StringProperty()
     userid = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class MainPage():
    field_name2 = 'userid'

    acct = Account.get_key(id).get() 

    acct.username = "Bob"
    acct[**field_name2**] = "001"  ## How can I do something like this?
    acct.put()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because `ndb.Models` behave like normal Python objects, you can access fields dynamically with Python [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) and [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#setattr).

In your example:

```
    setattr(acct, field_name2, "001")
```

Give it a whirl at http://shell.appspot.com
See also: [How to dynamically access class properties in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425272/how-to-dynamically-access-class-properties-in-python)