# How to change an object's attribute with a method?

Tags: python

I have this code that stores a person's name, age and funds. I am trying to write a method that can take "age" or "funds", along with a number, and increase the given attribute by that number.

```
class Actor:
    def __init__(self, name, age, funds):
        self.name
        self.age = age
        self.funds = funds

    def increase_age(self, increase_amount=1):
        self.age = self.age + increase_amount

    def increase_attrib(self, attrib, increase_amount=1):
        self.attrib = self.attrib + increase_amount

a = Actor("Andrea", 32, 10000)
```

`a.increase_age()` works fine: calling it increases the age of Andrea to 33, just as expected. However, `a.increase_attrib("age")` gives an error, saying `AttributeError: 'Actor' object has no attribute 'attrib'`. `a.increase_attrib("funds")` gives similar results.

If I just say `a.increase_attrib(age)` (without the quotes) I get a NameError, which is what I expected.

By my understanding, giving the parameter `"age"` to `increase_attrib()` should mean that the `attrib` mentioned becomes `age`, so that `increase_attrib()` references `self.age` instead of `self.attrib`. Apparently, I was wrong.

Now, I could just use `increase_age()` instead, but then I'd have to make different methods for age and funds, and even more methods once I add other features to `Actor`, like location, gender, and nationality.

What do I need to do so that I can pass the name of an attribute to a method and have it change that attribute?

Comment: Are you after `setattr(self, attrib, getattr(self, attrib) + increase_amount)`? If so, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1167398/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`setattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr):

```
setattr(obj, 'foo', 42)
```

Is the same as

```
obj.foo = 42
```

So for your example:

```
def increase_attrib(self, attrib, increase_amount=1):
    setattr(self, attrib, getattr(self, attrib, 0) + increase_amount)
```