# How to generate variables in a particular class?

Tags: python

I am building a physics engine in python, and am trying to make a function, preferably a generator, which makes a defined number of variables with systematically assigned names in the self-defined class "particle." 
But to do so, I need to alter the variable name with each iteration, for which I need to alter the code in the function itself, which is hard to find tutorials of. 
My target is something along the lines of

```py
def gen_parts(part_amount, basename, mass, charge):
  counter_2 = 0
  while counter_2 < part_amount:
    #generate position and velocity: v = [v_x, v_y] and s = [s_x, s_y]
    name = basename+"_"+str(counter)
    code(name) = GenPart(counter, s, v, mass, charge) #I need the code() function from here, somehow
    counter += 1
```

**How can I do this?**

Comment: possible duplication of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167398/python-access-class-property-from-string

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: access class property from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167398/python-access-class-property-from-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612610/how-to-access-object-attribute-given-string-corresponding-to-name-of-that-attrib)

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to dynamically generate differently-named attributes (it's possible, but you don't want to do it).  Instead you want your class attribute to be some sort of data structure (like a `List` or a `Dict`) and just add your attributes to it.  If you just want to keep an ordered list of them (like you want to make 10 vectors or whatever), a `List` is good; if you want to associate them with some other data (like names) then that's what a `Dict` is for.

It might look something like:

```
def gen_parts(self, part_amount, mass, charge):
    self.parts = []  # initialize self.parts to be an empty list
    while len(self.parts) < part_amount:
        #generate position and velocity: v = [v_x, v_y] and s = [s_x, s_y]
        self.parts.append(GenPart(s, v, mass, charge))
```

I took out the `counter` and `basename` on the theory that they're needless complications; the list (`self.parts`) automatically keeps track of how many elements it contains and makes each element uniquely accessible by its index (the order in which it was added).