# how can i combine 2 strings to 1 string?

Tags: python

I want to create a string from 2 strings that I use in a function. It is the `zz` that I use in the function `geraeusche.mach_geraeusche(2000, "hupen")`
but I can't create that. I get the following error message:

> descriptor 'play' for 'Sound' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object

My code:

```
class Geraeusche(pygame.sprite.Sprite):       
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self) 
        self.startzeit = 0 
        self.zaehler = 0    
        self.martinshorn = pygame.mixer.Sound("Bilder/martinshorn.mp3")
        self.hupen = pygame.mixer.Sound("Bilder/horn.wav") 
    
    def mach_geraeusche(self,warten,auswahl):
    
        if self.zaehler < 10:

            aktuelle_zeit = pygame.time.get_ticks()
                
            if aktuelle_zeit - self.startzeit > warten:
                self.startzeit = aktuelle_zeit
                self.zaehler +=1
            
                zz=str("self." + auswahl)
                pygame.mixer.Sound.play(zz)              

while True:
    clock.tick(60)   
    geraeusche.mach_geraeusche(2000,"hupen")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two issues here.

First, the way you are trying to access the class attribute will not work - **zz** will just be the string ‘self.hupen’ and will not actually point to that attribute. The correct way to do this is:

```
zz = getattr(self, auswahl)
```

as per [Python: access class property from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167398/python-access-class-property-from-string).

Second, this doesn’t appear to be the correct way to initialise and play sounds in pygame. It should be:

```
my_sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(zz)
pygame.mixer.Sound.play(my_sound)
```

as per https://pythonprogramming.net/adding-sounds-music-pygame/

Comment: Thank you. It works. But i want the sound "hupen " and "martinshorn" I get only "hupen"  geraeusche.mach_geraeusche(2000,"hupen")   geraeusche.mach_geraeusche(4000,"martinshorn")? You have an idea?

Comment: Sorry but I’m not sure I follow you - could you include your code and clearly explain what’s happening?

Comment: the code is above. was part of my earlier question. the claas Geraeusche and thefunction and the function def mach_geraeusche(self,warten,auswahl): and the calling geraeusche.mach_geraeusche(2000,"hupen")

Comment: When i call in the while loop  geraeusche.mach_geraeusche(2000,"hupen")  and geraeusche.mach_geraeusche(2000,"martinshorn") then i only get "hupen"