# Convert a string value to variable part

Tags: python-3.x, string, converters

I am trying to convert a string input as part of variable.

Ex :

lets say input string is A

```
Api.setting = Setting.SetA
```

if input string is 1

```
Api.setting = Setting.Set1
```

I have implemented with all possible cases like

```
if input1 == "A":
    Api.setting = Setting.SetA
elif input1 == "1":
    Api.setting = Setting.Set1
```

etc;

I am unsure if I have covered all possible cases or not. And also if new cases come, I need to add new elif conditions.

Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: `input` is the built-in function. Do not use it as a variable name. Everything else in your post is completely unclear. What are `Setting.SetA` and `Setting.Set1`?

Comment: Setting.SetA and Sett.ingSet1 are API imported from a dll. We are assigning the values according to the input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: access class property from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167398/python-access-class-property-from-string)

Answer (score -2):

I think you call directly with the input variable

Example:

```
Api.setting = Setting.Set + str(input)
```